# kile editor not working in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: kile

[image: 1][image: my]
[image: 3]

my kile editor is not working, i mean I am not able to open my tex files in kile at all, even I am open kile and then new pdf/beamer etc ..nothing is coming at all.

Comment: Does any other editor work? Can you compile tex files from command line? Does kile have settings, that associate kile with tex? Did kile work for your before, but now suddenly stopped working?

Comment: open a kind of terminal and type `kile &` and watch out for error messages. I used kile years ago and getting such a blank frame always meant I had broken something.

Comment: no other editor is working, no cant compile, yes worked since last 2 year

Comment: attached errorrrr

Comment: This is an error connected to kile, not the tex engine. If you google the error message `X error: badWindow (invalid Window paratmeter ) 3`, you'll find a lot of threads. I suggest to move the question to the ask Ubuntu site.